# how to merge faces to make the final face subdividable

Tags: cycles-render-engine, faces

I'm wondering what's the proper way of merging adjacent faces so that the final face is subdividable by loopcuts or subdivide function. Cheers

For the example below, loopcuts are not displayed on the mesh and subdivide function splits only the edges but not the face

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems you choose in the last two pictures to subdivide one unique face. You may start from a shape done with 3 rectangles to have the faces subdivision

Comment: You need to give a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

- 1/ is the face you are starting from
- 2/ is the result you have with a subdivision
- 3/ shows 1 triangulated (the inner geometry of the 1 ngon)
- 4/ the result that is obtained applying a subdivision to 3

[image]

You may proceed with a shape composed of 3 squares or rectangles, like this below :

- 1/ no more ngons but 3 quads
- 2/ the result after a subdivision

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it's still a little unclear to me how i get from the 1st picture - 2/ - subdivied edges  to 2nd picture /1 - 3quads

Comment: There is also the pretty cool Grid Fill, but that may require you to Subdivide so that you have a mesh looking like #2 first.

Comment: @FishBone, as fas as I know you'll have to do it manually. As for the shape of your question, nothing is regular, so nothing can be done in one click. The process is surely to 'X'/dissolve the vertices between the corners, subdivide only top and left edge and align these new vertices. Do you need a more detailed explanation for that ?

Comment: no thank you, so i got to do the donkey work, thanks! :D i thought there is some workaround but there isnt unfortunately, yet